# Why is my implementation of C++ map not storing values?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a class called ImageMatrix, which implements the C++ map in a recursive fashion; the end result is that I have a 3 dimensional array.

```
typedef uint32_t VUInt32;
typedef int32_t VInt32;

class ImageMatrix
{
public:
    ImageMatrixRow operator[](VInt32 rowIndex)
private:
    ImageMatrixRowMap rows;
};

typedef std::map <VUInt32, VInt32> ImageMatrixChannelMap;

class ImageMatrixColumn
{
public:
    VInt32 &operator[](VUInt32 channelIndex);
private:
    ImageMatrixChannelMap channels;
};

typedef std::map<VUInt32, ImageMatrixColumn> ImageMatrixColumnMap;

class ImageMatrixRow
{
public:
    ImageMatrixColumn operator[](VUInt32 columnIndex);
private:
    ImageMatrixColumnMap columns;
};

typedef std::map<VUInt32, ImageMatrixRow> ImageMatrixRowMap;
```

Each operator simply returns a map-wrapper class within, like so:

```
ImageMatrixRow ImageMatrix::operator[](VInt32 rowIndex)
{
    return rows[rowIndex];
}

ImageMatrixColumn ImageMatrixRow::operator[](VUInt32 columnIndex)
{
    return columns[columnIndex];
}

VInt32 &ImageMatrixColumn::operator[](VUInt32 channelIndex)
{
    return channels[channelIndex];
}
```

Basically, when I set the value as say 100, and test the value to cout, it shows as 0, and not the number to which I had set it.

```
for (VUInt32 a = 0; a < GetRowCount(); a++)
{
    for (VUInt32 b = 0; b < GetColumnCount(); b++)
    {
        for (VUInt32 c = 0; c < GetChannelCount(); c++)
        {
            VInt32 value = 100;
            matrix[a][b][c] = value;

            VInt32 test = matrix[a][b][c];

                            // pixel = 100, test = 0 - why?
            cout << pixel << "/" << test << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I've altered the original code for this example so that it takes up less space, so some syntax errors may occur (please don't point them out).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following operators return by value, no writes modify the actual data.

```
ImageMatrixRow ImageMatrix::operator[](VInt32 rowIndex);

ImageMatrixColumn ImageMatrixRow::operator[](VUInt32 columnIndex);
```

Use:

```
ImageMatrixRow& ImageMatrix::operator[](VInt32 rowIndex)


ImageMatrixColumn& ImageMatrixRow::operator[](VUInt32 columnIndex)
```

Comment: Yep, and his code only compiles by chance because he remembered to return a reference from ImageMatrixColumn::operator[]

Comment: Thanks, how embarrassing! I honestly thought that I was returning references... should have paid more attention at university :p

Answer (score 1):

All your operator[] functions except one return values - they should all return references.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageMatrixRow` and `ImageMatrixColumn` `operator[]()` methods return copies, not referecencs.

Answer (score 0):

"Each returns a reference" - are you sure about that?

They look like they return copies of the stored maps, not references to them.

Try, for example:

```
ImageMatrixRow & ImageMatrix::operator[](VInt32 rowIndex)
```

Note the `&` symbol.